# HTML code in a specific format

Tags: python, html

I have the HTMl code @http://pastie.org/8456333 as a reference ,also I have the below code where i am construcing HTML code to email ..i need inputs or suggestions on what modifcations need to be done to below code to make the table look like
the HTML code @http://pastie.org/8456333

```
import re
import os
import sys
import time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_call,Popen,PIPE

def email (body,subject,to=None):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    msg["From"] = "cdit@company.com"
    #msg["From"] = "test@company.com"
    if to!=None:
        to=to.strip()
        #msg["To"] = "test@company.com"
        msg["To"] = to
    else:
        msg["To"] = to
    msg["Subject"] = '%s' % subject
    p = Popen(["/usr/sbin/sendmail", "-t"], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(msg.as_string())

def  manifest_table(project,branch):
    global table_items
    global tableProperties
    table_items = table_items + "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>"%(project,branch)
    tableBody = """\
                <style type="text/css">
                %s
                </style>
                <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
                %s
                </table>
            """%(tableProperties, table_items)
    return tableBody

def main ():
    i=0
    global table_items
    table_items = "<tr><th>Project</th><th>Branch</th></tr>"
    global tableProperties
    tableProperties = r"table.tftable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:10%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;} table.tftable th {font-size:12px;background-color:#ded0b0;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:left;} table.tftable tr {background-color:#ffffff;} table.tftable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;}"
    project_list=['data','modem','1x','umts']
    branch_list=['jb','fr','kk','choc']
    for proj in project_list:
        branch = branch_list[i]
        mft = manifest_table(proj,branch)
        i=i+1
    email_body = """\
            <html>
              <head></head>
              <body>
                <p>Please find the table for the gerrits you provided:- <br>
                </p>
                %s
              </body>
            </html>
            """%(mft)
    print "Emailing..."
    email(email_body,"Manifest table","test@company.com")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Seems like a good task for a template engine like Jinja2. That said, questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: @PauloScardine - did you see my code above?it shows what I have tried and if you run you will see the results

Comment: I may help if the question is well stated and the problem is interesting enough. I will not run your code nor fix it, this site is stackoverflow.com, not do-my-homework-for-me.com. BTW this code looks like a SPAM thrower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making your table I suggest to use string.Template:
this is simple example:

```
from string import Template
a = Template("$name is my friend")
b=a.substitute(name="Sara")
print b
#output: Sara is my friend
```

So about a part of your code:

```
table_items = table_items + "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>"%(project,branch)
```

you can do it better:

```
table_items += "<tr><td>%(p)s</td><td>%(b)s</td></tr>" % {'p':project,'b':branch}
```

or via string.Template:

```
table_items = Template("<tr><td>$p</td><td>$b</td></tr>")
table_items += table_items.substitute(p=project,b=branch)
```